# Wget: Filenames without the query string

Tags: wget

I want to download a list of webpages from a file. How can I stop Wget appending the query strings on to the saved files?

```
wget http://www.example.com/index.html?querystring
```

I need this to be downloaded as `index.html`, not `index.html?querystring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the -O option:

```
wget -O file.html http://www.example.com/index.html?querystring
```

so you can alter a little bit your script to pass to the `-O` argument the right file name.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally resigned to using the `-O` and just wrapped it in a bash function to make it easier.  I put this in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
wget-rmq ()
{
  [ -z "$1" ] && echo 'error: wget-rmq requires a URL to retrieve as the first arg'
  local output_filename="$(echo $1 | sed 's/?.*//g' | sed 's|https.*/||g')"
  wget -O "${output_filename}" "${1}"
}
```

Then when I want to download a file:

```
wget-rmq http://www.example.com/index.html?querystring
```

The replacement regex is fairly simple.  If any `?`s appear in the URL before the query string begins then it will break.  In practice that hasn't happened though since URL encoding requires `?` to be in URLs as `%3F`, but I wanted to note the possibility.